# Using Perl or Linux built-in command-line tools how quickly map one integer to another?

Tags: linux, perl, command-line, awk

I have a text file mapping of two integers, separated by commas:

```
123,456
789,555
...
```

It's 120Megs... so it's a very long file.

I keep to search for the first column and return the second, e.g., look up 789 --returns--> 555 and I need to do it FAST, using regular Linux built-ins.

I'm doing this right now and it takes several seconds per look-up.

If I had a database I could index it.  I guess I need an indexed text file!

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
my $lineFound=`awk -F, '/$COLUMN1/ { print $2 }' ../MyBigMappingFile.csv`;
```

Is there any easy way to pull this off with a performance improvement?

Comment: How often does the mapping data change and how often do you need to query a mapping?

Comment: What about reading the whole file into a Perl hash? If your Perl script doesn't run for very long, perhaps you could use a tied hash, but you'll need to recreate it every time the mappings change.

Comment: sqlite3 can be used to create an indexed file.  It is very common.  Do you consider it a built-in command-line tool?

Comment: Are the numbers in the first column unique, or can one lookup return several results?

Comment: Your awk command, given `123`, will find `012,123`, as well as `1234,5678`.  You probably want to do an equality check on `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash suggestions are the natural way an experienced Perler would do this, but it may be suboptimal in this case. It scans the entire file and builds a large, flat datastructure in linear time. Cruder methods can short circuit with a worst case linear time, usually less in practice.

I first made a big mapping file:

```
my $LEN = shift;
for (1 .. $LEN) {
    my $rnd = int rand( 999 );
    print "$_,$rnd\n";
}
```

With `$LEN` passed on the command line as 10000000, the file came out to 113MB. Then I benchmarked three implemntations. The first is the hash lookup method. The second slurps the file and scans it with a regex. The third reads line-by-line and stops when it matches. Complete implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw{timethese};

my $FILE  = shift;
my $COUNT = 100;
my $ENTRY = 40;


slurp(); # Initial file slurp, to get it into the hard drive cache

timethese( $COUNT, {
    'hash'       => sub { hash_lookup( $ENTRY ) },
    'scalar'     => sub { scalar_lookup( $ENTRY ) },
    'linebyline' => sub { line_lookup( $ENTRY ) },
});


sub slurp
{
    open( my $fh, '<', $FILE ) or die "Can't open $FILE: $!\n";
    undef $/;
    my $s = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    return $s;
}

sub hash_lookup
{
    my ($entry) = @_;
    my %data;

    open( my $fh, '<', $FILE ) or die "Can't open $FILE: $!\n";
    while( <$fh> ) {
        my ($name, $val) = split /,/;
        $data{$name} = $val;
    }
    close $fh;

    return $data{$entry};
}

sub scalar_lookup
{
    my ($entry) = @_;
    my $data = slurp();
    my ($val) = $data =~ /\A $entry , (\d+) \z/x;
    return $val;
}

sub line_lookup
{
    my ($entry) = @_;
    my $found;

    open( my $fh, '<', $FILE ) or die "Can't open $FILE: $!\n";
    while( <$fh> ) {
        my ($name, $val) = split /,/;
        if( $name == $entry ) {
            $found = $val;
            last;
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    return $found;
}
```

Results on my system:

```
Benchmark: timing 100 iterations of hash, linebyline, scalar...
      hash: 47 wallclock secs (18.86 usr + 27.88 sys = 46.74 CPU) @  2.14/s (n=100)
linebyline: 47 wallclock secs (18.86 usr + 27.80 sys = 46.66 CPU) @  2.14/s (n=100)
    scalar: 42 wallclock secs (16.80 usr + 24.37 sys = 41.17 CPU) @  2.43/s (n=100)
```

(Note I'm running this off an SSD, so I/O is very fast, and perhaps makes that initial `slurp()` unnecessary. YMMV.)

Interestingly, the `hash` implementation is just as fast as `linebyline`, which isn't what I expected. By using slurping, `scalar` may end up being faster on a traditional hard drive.

<strike>However, by far the fastest is a simple call to `grep`:</strike>

```
$ time grep '^40,' int_map.txt 
40,795

real    0m0.508s
user    0m0.374s
sys     0m0.046
```

Perl could easily read that output and split apart the comma in hardly any time at all.

Edit: Never mind about grep. I misread the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

120 meg isn't that big.  Assuming you've got at least 512MB of ram, you could easily read the whole file into a hash and then do all of your lookups against that.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
sed -n "/^$COLUMN1/{s/.*,//p;q}" file
```

This optimizes your code in three ways:
1) No needless splitting each line in two on ",".
2) You stop processing the file after the first hit.
3) sed is faster than awk.

This should more than half your search time.

HTH Chris

Comment: I was skeptical of this claim, but at least on my machine, with the 10,000 lines of random test data I created (typically 5-digit numbers, generated with Bash `echo $RANDOM,$RANDOM`), it was much faster than that, even.  `awk` took almost 2 1/2 minutes, `sed` completed the same in 24 seconds. (I added a comma after `COLUMN` in order to avoid false matches, in the original `awk` script and this one.)  Still, a hash in Perl is what I would suggest if at all feasible.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how often the data change and how often in the course of a single script invocation you need to look up.

If there are many lookups during each script invocation, I would recommend parsing the file into a hash (or array if the range of keys is narrow enough).

If the file changes every day, creating a new SQLite database might or might not be worth your time.

If each script invocation needs to look up just one key, and if the data file changes often, you might get an improvement by slurping the entire file into a scalar (minimizing memory overhead, and do a pattern match on that (instead of parsing each line).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

die "Need key\n" unless @ARGV;

my $lookup_file = 'lookup.txt';
my ($key) = @ARGV;

my $re = qr/^$key,([0-9]+)$/m;

open my $input, '<', $lookup_file
    or die "Cannot open '$lookup_file': $!";

my $buffer = do { local $/; <$input> };

close $input;

if (my ($val) = ($buffer =~ $re)) {
    print "$key => $val\n";
}
else {
    print "$key not found\n";
}
```

On my old slow laptop, with a key towards the end of the file:

```
C:\Temp> dir lookup.txt
...
2011/10/14  10:05 AM       135,436,073 lookup.txt

C:\Temp> tail lookup.txt
4522701,5840
5439981,16075
7367284,649
8417130,14090
438297,20820
3567548,23410
2014461,10795
9640262,21171
5345399,31041

C:\Temp> timethis lookup.pl 5345399

5345399 => 31041

TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:03.343
```

Comment: In order to make our timings at least roughly comparable, what I did was look up each key in the file (see my comment to Chris' answer).  Timing a single lookup is not very useful.  Note that I used a much smaller file, though; 10,000 keys, 10,000 lookups.

Comment: Timing a single lookup enables a comparison with shelling out to `awk`. That was my intent.

Comment: Yes, but timing anything only once is subject to a number of disturbances.  The same reason statisticians ask more than one person when performing a poll.  Running the same test a thousand times and dividing by 1000 gives a better, more solid, more repeatable result.

Comment: To further expand on that, I would not do this if you have to look up many times. Here are some timings that will illustrate what I mean: 10 lookups 6.5 seconds, 100 lookups 37 seconds etc.

Comment: The result I posted was the fifth run. The first time, the file was not in the cache. The next few runs, I assume it was. There was no real difference: About 3 seconds run time each time. In comparison, when I used `File::Slurp`, run time went up by 2 seconds. And, please, spare me the stats lesson. We are talking about rough numbers here, not milliseconds.

Comment: Four consistent runs is way better than one run.  No offense, just trying to make sure we are not comparing apples with oranges.

Answer (score 0):

This example loads the file into a hash (which takes about 20s for 120M on my system). Subsequent lookups are then nearly instantaneous.  This assumes that each number in the left column is unique.  If that's not the case then you would need to push numbers on the right with the same number on the left onto an array or something.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($csv) = @ARGV;
my $start=time;
open(my $fh, $csv) or die("$csv: $!");
$|=1;
print("loading $csv... ");
my %numHash;
my $p=0;
while(<$fh>) { $p+=length; my($k,$v)=split(/,/); $numHash{$k}=$v }
print("\nprocessed $p bytes in ",time()-$start, " seconds\n");
while(1) { print("\nEnter number: "); chomp(my $i=<STDIN>); print($numHash{$i}) }
```

Example usage and output:

```
$ ./lookup.pl MyBigMappingFile.csv 
loading MyBigMappingFile.csv... 
processed 125829128 bytes in 19 seconds

Enter number: 123
322

Enter number: 456
93

Enter number:
```

Answer (score 0):

does it help if you cp the file to your `/dev/shm`, and using /awk/sed/perl/grep/ack/whatever query a mapping?

don't tell me you are working on a 128MB ram machine. :)